# Existence of a differentiable function $f$ such that the set of points at which $|f|$ is differentiable is not dense in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Does there exist  a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that the set of points at which $|f|$ is differentiable is not dense in $\mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 7):

No. In any interval, either the function is constant at 0 or it takes a non-zero value. Go from there.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then $|f|$ is differentiable at $c$ if $f(c)\neq 0$.

If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, and $f(c)=0$, then $|f|$ is differentiable at $c$ iff $f'(c)= 0$.

If the set of differentiable point of $|f|$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$, you have an open interval $I$, such that $f(x)=0,f'(x)\neq 0$ on $I$, which is impossible.